# Windows 2003 server RRAS on VPC

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, amazon-web-services, rras

I'm trying to setup a L2TP VPN server(to give user access on to all my VPN instance) on a Windows 2003 instance running on my VPC. While trying to enable RRAS I'm getting error, "less than two network interfaces were detected on this machine". Eventually it's because there's only one network interface available, the which has private IP. I have elastic IP assigned to this instance as well. But RRAS can't see this. What should I do to RRAS to be able to see the interface with elastic IP?

Answer (score 1):

When only one NIC is available you need to select the Custom configuration option in the RRAS setup wizard.

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty. I was able to get the PPTP working. Can connect with PPTP. But I can't access any other computer within the VPC. Any idea?

Comment: Did you enable LAN Routing in the RRAS setup/properties? If not then you need to do that. Without LAN Routing enabled the VPN client will only have access to the server but not to the LAN.